# Reshape data in R based on column order

Tags: r, reshape

I am looking to transpose an R data frame from wide to long format using the reshape function.  I have a long list of **122** columns that will be included as `varying=` terms.  I am looking for a way to list these columns based on their order in the data frame, rather than name each one individually?

A cut-down version of the reshape call with just 3 columns for `All` looks something like below. My actual version has a **much** longer vector for `varying=` that I would like to simplify.

```
AllReshape <- reshape(
             All, 
             varying = c("TotalSedges", "TotalGrasses",  "TotalRushes", etc...),
             v.names = "Percent",
             timevar = "ForageName",
             times = c("TotalSedges", "TotalGrasses",  "TotalRushes", etc...)
             direction = "long")
```

If my `varying` columns are columns 5-126 in my dataframe, can I use the column order/position instead of the individual variable (column) names when specifying my `varying` and `times` within `reshape`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at melt() in reshape2? Something like new_df <- melt(df, id.vars = 1:4, measure.vars = 5:126)

Comment: Did you try it? In the examples at `help(reshape)` they even have an example showing that you can use numeric positions instead.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? You're much more likely to get help that way.

Comment: Why not `varying = names(ALL)[5:126],` ? (Although, like Ananda, I was under the impression that just ``varying=5:126` would have worked.) Based on my experience with the reshape function I would guess that your errors lie elsewhere, but as has already been pointed out, you give no example and there is no way to test your code.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response.  I guess I need to read the help more thoroughly.  Here's my solution:                          `AllReshape <- reshape(All, varying = 7:122, timevar = "ForageName",
v.names = "Percent", times = names(All)[7:122],
direction = "long")`